# Open document function in Windows 7 with AIR App

Tags: actionscript-3, windows-7

Below is the code I'm working on to open a pdf file when a button is clicked.
It all works fine in Windows Vista and Windows 8+, but the pdf file gets opened only once in Windows 7.

By clicking the button again doesn't launch the pdf file the second time.

```
function openDoc(event: MouseEvent): void {

    nsStream.pause();
    pausedBtn.visible = true;    
    mcVideoControls.btnPause.visible            = false;
    mcVideoControls.btnPlay.visible     = true;


    var realFile: File = File.applicationDirectory.resolvePath(_myfilename);

    //get user's home directory:
    var destination: File = File.documentsDirectory;

    //copy the original file temponary to user's home directory:
    destination = destination.resolvePath(_myfilename);
    realFile.copyTo(destination, true);

    //open the temponary copy from user's home directory (acrobat or whatever):
    destination.openWithDefaultApplication();
        }



function onCuePoint(infoObject:Object):void 
{ 
    openDocBtn.visible = true;
    timer1.start();

    if (infoObject.name == "myDocCue"){


_myfilename = "mydoc.pdf"; // = my filename 

    }
```

Comment: why copy if it exist? if(!destination.exist){realFile,copyTo) ....}

Comment: The application runs on a DVD. Standalone without any install to user's hard drive. Trying to prevent the pdfs from getting saved. Do you think that might be why it's not opening the pdf for the second time in Windows 7?

Comment: try saving with a different name each time and see what happens.

Comment: There are literally about a hundred pdf flies :(

Comment: could you point me to a direction where I can set the filename differently each time the pdf launches?